I'm coding a Connect 4 game, but every time I drop a disk, it drops the disk in rows not columns
The game works, but it just the wrong way around. How will I go about dropping disks in columns? This isn't the full code (can't post the whole thing), I just think these functions are the ones most likely to have the error I'm looking for
def drop_disk(col, player):

    # Check if column is full
    if board[0][col] != 0:
        return "Column is full"

    # Find the lowest empty row in the chosen column
    for row in range(len(board)-1, -1, -1):
        if board[row][col] == 0:
            break

    # Drop the disk in that row
    board[row][col] = player
    return board


def have_winner():
    
    # Check horizontal spaces
    for row in range(len(board)):
        for col in range(len(board[0]) - 3):
            if board[row][col] == board[row][col + 1] == board[row][col + 2] == board[row][col + 3] != 0:
                return board[row][col]

    # Check vertical spaces
    for col in range(len(board[0])):
        for row in range(len(board) - 3):
            if board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col] == board[row + 2][col] == board[row + 3][col] != 0:
                return board[row][col]

    # Check \\ diagonals
    for row in range(len(board) - 3):
        for col in range(len(board[0]) - 3):
            if board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col + 1] == board[row + 2][col + 2] == board[row + 3][col + 3] != 0:
                return board[row][col]

    # Check / diagonals
    for row in range(3, len(board)):
        for col in range(len(board[0]) - 3):
            if board[row][col] == board[row - 1][col + 1] == board[row - 2][col + 2] == board[row - 3][col + 3] != 0:
                return board[row][col]

    return 0  # Return zero if no winner

game()

Where did I go wrong? What should I do?

I understand you want to drop the disks from top to bottom within a column, not from left to right across the row.
def drop_disk(col, player):
    # Find the lowest empty row in the chosen column
    for row in range(len(board)):
        if board[row][col] == 0:
            # Drop the disk in that row
            board[row][col] = player
            return board
    return "Column is full"

In this updated version, the loop iterates from the top to the bottom of the column. It checks each row in the column to find the first empty slot. If an empty slot is found, the disk is dropped in that row, and the updated board is returned. If the loop completes without finding an empty slot, it means the column is full, and "Column is full" is returned.
With this adjustment, the disks should now be dropped from top to bottom within each column

Hey Swetha, thanks for the response. Your code is written way better than mine but it still doesn't address the fact that the disks are being dropped from left to right. I might not have said it clear in the post but essentially, my code makes it seem that the right most column is the bottom of the board.

With the new edit, by changing the range, the disks are now dropping from right to left now
